# How does :g/^$/,/./-j (reduce multiple blank lines to a single blank) work in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

In the article, [Vim Regular Expressions](http://web.archive.org/web/20080306034905/http://www.geocities.com/volontir/), Oleg Raisky gives the following command to reduce multiple blank lines to a single blank:

```
:g/^$/,/./-j
```

Can someone please describe how this works?

I know `:g` command and regular expressions. But I didn't understand what the part `/,/./-j` does.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It really is quite ingenious. Let's break it down. The `ex` command

```
g/^$/xyzzy
```

will search for all empty lines and execute the `xyzzy` command (an arbitrary `ex` command) on each of them.

The tricky bit here is that the `xyzzy` command in your case is *yet another* substitute command:

```
,/./-j
```

The `,/./-` specifies a range. This is of the form `<start>,<end>` and, because there's nothing before the comma, it assumes the current line (the one where you found the blank line) is the start.

After the comma is `/./-` which means search for the next character (`.` means any character) then back up one line (`/./-` is short for `/./-1` since the one is implied if no value is given). You'll find that pattern `.` on the first non-blank line following the one you're operating on.

In other words, the end of the range is the last blank line after or at the one you're currently operating on.

Then you execute a join over that range.

If the start and the end of the range were equal (only one blank line was in the section), join does nothing. If they're not equal, join will join them all up.

That's the way in which it combines multiple blank lines into one.

Lets look at an example (line numbers are not in the file):

```
1 Line 1
2
3 Line 3
4 Line 4
5
6
7
8
9 Line 9
```

The `:g` command will find all blank lines and perform its operation on them (lines 2, 5, 6, 7 and 8).

For line 2, `,/./-j` will set up a range from 2 to 2 (next `.` found on line 3 then subtract 1). A join on the range 2,2 does nothing.

For line 5, `,/./-j` will set up a range from 5 to 8 (next `.` found on line 9 then subtract 1). A join on the range 5,8 will join all those lines together.

I'm not *entirely* certain about this but I think the operation may not be performed on lines that disappear as part of an earlier operation. That's because it would make no sense to process lines that have been deleted earlier in the cycle.

In other words, because lines 6 through 8 are deleted (combined with line 5), the global command doesn't operate on them after that. I base that on nothing more than the fact that the vim documentation states a two-pass algorithm, one to mark the lines, one to perform the operation.

I *may* be wrong on that point (it wouldn't be the first time) but it's an implementation detail which doesn't affect the functionality.

Comment: Thank you. This was very clarifying. I didn't know that "XYZ command" part of :g could specify a range.

Comment: The XYZ command can be any `ex` command, including another substitute. I imagine you could string a few more of them together if you wanted an even _crazier_ test of vim knowledge :-)

Comment: That is awesome! I was trying to figure out how to join multiple ex commands just the other day.. thanks.

Comment: I just tried out this command myself, and soon found it has one small flaw: Because of the way it works, multiple blank lines at the END of a file do not get merged! (This is because there is nothing for the "." to match.)

Comment: That's a good point @Tom, but it's a problem with the command itself rather than my answer :-) I've had a think about how best to modify it to handle both cases but have not come up with anything yet.

Comment: Another way to explain the range is that `,/./-` is equivalent to `.,/./-1`:  both the initial `.` and the trailing `1` can be left out.  I think the docs for `:help :g` are clear about not executing the command on lines that have already been deleted:  `In a second scan the [cmd] is executed for each marked line with its line number prepended.  ...  If a line is deleted its mark disappears.`  The XYZ command cannot be any `ex` command:  you are not allowed to nest `:g` commands.  That may be the only exception.

Comment: So I like this answer because it explains it, but is there any sane reason why I should bother to try to keep this explanation in my head, when a readily understandable solution in the form of `:%s/\(\n\n\)\n\+/\1/` exists?

Comment: @Steven, to (mis)quote Douglas Adams, this must be some _new_ definition of the word "understandable" of which I was previously unaware :-) No, seriously, it appears your solution also does the same thing so can be substituted for the specific case, but it's still nice to know about the `g` command, which can do _far_ more than just substitute on the matching lines.

Comment: Well, yes I do agree that the `g` command is good to know, indeed it is probably one of the most powerful features available with Vim, but as you concede in your answer, one must consider *many* factors (such as  "how will I be affected by the restriction that each line is processed only once") when embarking on composing such a `g` command. To me, the use of `j` join is not obvious. It has to occur to me that `j` is appropriate to use in the situation, which it happens to be. It is far more sensible to think of the "reduce multiple blank lines" task to a regex replacement operation.

Comment: All that being said.... Your answer **remains** a perfect answer to the original question which specifically asks "WTH is this magic `:g` incantation?", so it is actually a bit improper of me to admonish it in the way that I did. I guess all I wanted to add to this discussion is that the original task (reduce multiple blank lines to a single one) should be answered with a regex replace, not a grazy `g` command.  And in closing, I will go on a bit of a tangent: I first became familiar with the `g` command through [this curiously fun website](http://vimgolf.com).

Comment: @paxdiablo Is there anyway to modify the command to include empty lines with whitespace (space, tabs etc)? I tried `:g/^\s*$/,/./-j` but it didn't work

Comment: @vexe, that probably should be a different question since it will get more attention than a comment to someone's answer. Have done that for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303768/how-can-i-collapse-multiple-white-space-lines-with-vim

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks, after some searching I found this, works perfectly! `:%s/^\_s\+\n/\r`