# How to go to the last non-blank line in a large text file with VI?

Tags: vi

I have very large text file with an occasional blank line in it, and with a large area of blank lines at the bottom.

I can go to the absolute bottom with "G" but how do I go back up to the last line where the blank area began? Or how do I search for "5 consequetive blank lines"?

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3032189/1154965) useful.

Comment: Are you only interested in vi compatible solutions, or would a vim solution suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
G
?.
```

`G` goes to the bottom. `?` searches backward for a regular expression, `.` is a regex that matches any character.