# How can I collapse multiple whitespace lines with vim?

Tags: regex, vim

The [question and answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032030/how-does-g-j-reduce-multiple-blank-lines-to-a-single-blank-work-in-vi) cover in detail how the following `vim` command collapses a series of empty lines into a single line:

```
:g/^$/,/./-j
```

However, I want to do the same but also treat lines with onlywhite space in them as blank. The following command is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
:g/^\s*$/,/./-j
```

As far as I can tell, that should find the lines that are empty and have only whitespace on them, but not all lines are being collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there.

Remember that the initial command consisted of a search part and an action part. The search part `:g/^$/` found all empty lines and the action part `,/./-j` was executed for each (well, each that hadn't already been deleted by a previous `j`).

The modification you made to the search part of the string is correct in that it will now find lines that are either empty or contain only whitespace.

However, it's the *action* that you're executing after that that's causing you grief. The original action to be executed on the found line was `,/./-j` which basically means execute a join `j` over the range from this line to the one before the next 'real' character. More detail on how this works can be found in the question you linked to.

The first 'real' character that it finds in your case actually *includes* whitespace so, while the search bit will find whitespace lines and act on them, the range of the join in the action will not be what you want.

What you need to specify for the end of the range in the action is the line previous to the next one that has something *other* than whitespace (rather than just a line with any 'real' character). A line with a non-whitespace character is simply one that matches the regex `\S` (the backslash with uppercase `S` denotes a non-whitespace character).

So, in the end, what you're looking for is:

```
:g/^\s*$/,/\S/-j
```

Having said that, keep in mind that the line that remains behind is (I think) the first from the range. So, it's not necessarily empty, it may contain white-space.

If you wish to ensure all whitespace-only lines are made empty, just execute:

```
:g/^\s*$/s/.*//
```

after the collapsing command above. Or, you can combine both into a single command using `|` as an action separator:

```
:g/^\s*$/,/\S/-j|s/.*//
```

Comment: Or just `:g/^\s*$/,/\S/-j`.

Comment: Good point, @Sato, that's a bit simpler. Adjusted the answer accordingly.