# Why a line return is added after every letter here

Tags: vim

I have following text in a file:

```
a line




another line
new line
```

I am trying to replace multiple carriage returns and replacing them by one carriage return only. I am trying following code:

```
:%s/\v\n*/\r/g
```

However, though above code replaces multiple blank lines by one, it also leads to a carriage return be added after every letter:

```
a

l
i
n
e
a
n
o
t
h
e
r

l
i
n
e
n
e
w

l
i
n
e
```

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing that because `\n*` means any number of newlines, *including zero* of them.

So that pattern actually occurs in-between each character pair. More specifically, in the string `ab`, there are actually zero of more newlines (in fact, zero or more of *any* character) between the `a` and `b`. That's because "zero of something" is a proper subset of "zero or more of something".

If you use `\n+` (meaning *one* or more newlines), it should be closer to what you want:

```
a line
another line
new line
```

You could also achieve a similar effect by the use of text processing tools outside of `vim`, such as with:

```
sed '/^$/d' inputFile >outputFile
```

---

That's assuming you want to collapse multiple newline characters in to one.

If your intent is to instead collapse multiple *blank lines* in to one, so that there's still a blank line between `a line` and `another line`, you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032030/how-does-g-j-reduce-multiple-blank-lines-to-a-single-blank-work-in-vi), which I have answered previously.